# закрыть tab bootstrap при скроллинге

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

```
 <span class="dropdown">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

как можно закрыть бутстраповский tab при скроллинге?

Comment: посмотреть в коде, как он открывается, и закрыть соответствующим образом, отлавливая событие скролла в нужный момент

Comment: Вы говорите [про табы](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), а в коде - выпадающий список. Что же всё-таки нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для открытия списка родителю навешивается класс `.open`. Если его убрать, то список закроется. Можно сделать, например, обработчик события на прокрутку окна.
Если нужно переключить состояние определенного выпадающего списка, то можно использовать `$('селектор').dropdown('toggle')`.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var dropdowns = $('.dropdown-toggle');
  $.each(dropdowns, function(i, c) {
    $(c).parent().removeClass('open');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.btn-group {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```